# How do I find out what version of reportlab I'm running?

Tags: python, reportlab

I need to know what version of reportlab I'm running.

The following doesn't seem to work.

```
import reportlab
print reportlab.__version__
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try:

```
print reportlab.Version
```